# Fix broken image urls

Tags: migration, hyperlink, powershell

I have migrated some websites from SharePoint 2007 to 2013 and there are some broken links, like images and links. As far as I know they are absolute links.
Can anyone show me how can I fix these links using PowerShell?

I have not been able to find an example so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of links.

1. Relative
2. Absolute

Relative URL will work without any issue. But Absolute URL are hard to fix. It can appear in anywhere on the Site. I am not sure using PowerShell it can be fixed in all the places.

On one of my recent migration project we did it manually by dividing it among our team members (changing it to relative)